# Bluetooth connection not working with new audio/video receiver

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa

I've been using Bluetooth to connect my laptop to my audio receiver for years. I use Blueman on the laptop with an adapter on the receiver.

Recently my receiver went out and now I have a new receiver, built in BT, and a new a BT/USB adapter for the laptop (since this issue).  The devices connect easily but no sound out.

When connected, the receiver connection is not always listed as an Output in Sound settings.  When it is listed (High Fidelity Playback Sink) there's still no sound output.  Selecting the play sound feature does nothing.

Same issue on two different laptops running 20.04 and up to date.  Also tried two other USB BT adapters.  One is brand new.

Works in Windows 10.
Phone BT works great over receiver.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

i think then problem is with your pluseaudio.
try to select your bluetooth device in pulseaudio.

make sure you have installed  all required modules related to bluetooth and pulseaudio as well.

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth -y 
sudo apt install --reinstall bluez -y 
sudo modprobe btusb 
puseaudio -k
```

now open your pulseaudio , it should solve your problem if it dont work then reboot your pc and  then  run following command in terminal after reboot:

```
sudo modprobe btusb 
puseaudio -k
```

Comment: Followed your instructions (thanks for helping) and saw some changes but still no sound. 

Now receiver shows up consistently in PA once paired and connected in either bluez or blueman. The buttons for test sound are visible now too.  Still no sound from test sound or applications.  Vlc doesn't hang like SMPlayer does but despite both apps showing receiver as audio destination still no sound.  Any other ideas appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: you need to give exact  error message what blueman gives you while connecting.
one thing you can do turn off  Secure Boot. go to your bios setting and turn it off there.
if your secure boot is on sometimes bluetooth dont work properly.
repeat all above command and start pc in secure boot off , Tell me it works or not